# Html <div> element background image not displaying and nothing inside of the div also

Tags: css, html, image, divide

I have a body with a background image and another  element with a background image of this div. The div I want to have yet another image [third one on the page] is not showing up. Nothing I put inside of the div is showing up either. Here is my code

```
<div id="middle" style="background-image: url(images/Home/binary.png); height: 200px; width: 1350px; border: 1px solid black;> 
    <h1>test</h1>
<[div]>
```

This is what I want to have a background image. I am sure that the source to that image is correct, I have checked it.
Here is my body.

```
<body background="images\Home\diamond.png">
```

This is working perfectly fine
Here is the header div with another background image [working fine]

```
<div id="top" style="background-image: url(images/Home/stars.png); height: 95px; width: 1350px; border: 1px solid black;>
```

I don't see the problem here. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: His code is posted, it's just not working. See my edit to review the code! Or I've posted an answer with it slightly modified.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `"` in your div.

```
<div id="middle" style="background-image: url("images/Home/binary.png"); height: 200px; width: 1350px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

As a note, try to always separate your CSS from your HTML, by putting it in another file.

Comment: Now there is a black line outlining the div... The things inside of the div are showing now but the image is not, just a black outline. I tried switching out the image for another but still does the black line outline.

Comment: Try background-image: url("images/Home/binary.png");.

Comment: I found the problem, if I put the style in the css file it does that black outline. If I put it inside of the div it works perfectly fine... Still, do you know the problem, the css file is messing up the images.

Comment: I'd need to see your CSS to help you on that.. Did you try my second correction?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.
CSS File for those tags
#top
{
    background-image: url("images/Home/stars.png");
    height: 95px;
    width: 1350px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#middle
{
    background-image: url("images/Home/binary.png");
    height: 95px;
    width: 1350px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

Comment: You shouldn't set style both in the CSS and in the HTML. Try to just use `<div id="middle">`

Comment: I did try that, still has that black box outline.

Comment: The black outline comes from the `border`. I've just tried your code here with one of my images, it works flawlessly.

Comment: I guess I will just stick to having the style in the div element, I don't know what is wrong. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

As Docteur said your missing a `"` in the starting tag of your div. What he also fixed but didn't mention was your closing tag `<[div]>` which should be `</div>`

If your getting as you call it

> a black line outlining the div

This is because you've set a black 1px border `border: 1px solid black;`

Try this:

```
<div id="middle" style="background-image: url("images/Home/binary.png"); height: 200px; width: 1350px;">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

Also have you checked to see if the file is in that directory, has a different file name or isn't corrupted?

Comment: Thanks for checking that question back - I don't know how I missed that border!